# Apple's typical device refresh optimal for new college students?

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, ipad, mac, imac

**Long-story-short:** When does apple typically update their hardware?

---

As a prospective college student, I'd want to get new devices before college begins, but I'd also prefer to have the most up-to-date once I actually begin college.

Colleges that I've looked into typically start in Fall, so I was wondering whether Apple typically updates devices in late-Summer. Or, do they inconveniently update it after most colleges start?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a comprehensive [Buyers' Guide](http://buyersguide.macrumors.com) at MacRumors, which provides the average product cycle lengths (and date of latest product update).

Comment: Thanks! I knew about MacRumors, but totally forgot to check their Buyers' Guide.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this question before joining my college. I would suggest you to wait till July and get which ever mac that suits your budget.

My personal advice would be to get something which is ultra portable like Macbook pro 13'inch or Air. I DONT think apple will be launching any updated Air anytime soon.

So you should **get the 13'Inch MacbookPro**.

Comment: I would wait until they update the Pro. It's rumored that they'll do so at WWDC.